# generalized affine scheme

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, affine-schemes

I'm thinking about following theorem.

For a finitaly algebraic theory $\mathbb{T}$, $\text{FP}\mathbb{T}$ denotes the full subcategory of $\mathbb{T}\text{-Alg(Set)}$ consisting of finitely presented algebras. $F:\mathbb{T} \rightarrow \text{FP}\mathbb{T}^{op}$ is $n\mapsto \text{hom}_{\mathbb{T}}(n,-)$.

**Theorem**

Given a left exact category $E$. Then, to any $\mathbb{T}$-algebra $R: \mathbb{T} \rightarrow E$, there exists a left exact functor $\overline{R}: \text{FP}\mathbb{T}^{\text{op}}\rightarrow E$ such that $\overline{R}\circ F = R$.

$\text{Spec}_R(B)$ denotes $\overline{R}(B)$ for $B \in \text{FP}\mathbb{T}$. For a field $k$, $T_k$ denotes the algebraic theory whose morphisms $n\rightarrow m$ are m-tuples of polynomials over $k$ in $n$ variables.

Assume that $k$ is a field, $\mathbb{T} = \mathbb{T}_k$, $E = \text{Set}$, $R=k:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow E ; n\mapsto k^n$, $B(m) = (k[X_1,...,X_n]/I)^m$ for all $m$, where $I$ is an ideal in $k[X_1, ..., X_n]$.

Then, I think $\text{Spec}_R(B)$ is expected to be the zero points of $I$, but how to prove this?

Comment: Can you do this if you use the standard definitions of field/ring/etc.?

Comment: I understand that if $k$ is algebraically closed, $R=k[X_1,...,X_n]/I$ and $\text{Spec}(R)$ is defined to be the maximal ideals of $R$, then zero points of $I$ correspond to elements of $\text{Spec}(R)$.

Comment: Sure. But that's not really the point. Forget about algebraic theories for the time being. What you are asking for is a left exact functor $\bar{R} : \mathbf{FPAlg}_k^\mathrm{op} \to \mathbf{Set}$ such that $\bar{R} (k [X_1, \ldots, X_n]) = k^n$ in a canonical way – there is really only one way of doing this.

Comment: I haven't came up with any idea. I might lack some fundamental knowledge. For $B\in \text{FPAlg}_{k}^{\text{op}}$, a coequalizer $F(m)\rightrightarrows F(n) \rightarrow B$ exists from the definition, but I don't know how to use these diagrams.

Comment: That diagram is very important. Since $\bar{R}$ is left exact, coequalisers in $\mathbf{FPAlg}_k^\mathrm{op}$ are sent to equalisers in $\mathbf{Set}$.

Comment: Although I don't know how $\bar{R}$ is defined, now I understand that there is a equalizer $\text{Spec}_{R}(B)\rightarrow R^n\rightrightarrows R^m$ in $\text{Set}$ and thus $\text{Spec}(B)$ must be the common zeros of $m$ polynomials of $n$ variables.